# Dynamic Maven project properties not getting replaced in resources

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I was trying to use `properties-maven-plugin` to read project properties at build time and then replace properties in a text file using `maven-resources-plugin`. Following are their declarations:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sample.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
              </includes>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Here are the contents of `sample.properties` and `hello.txt` present at `src/main/resources`

```
sample.properties
name=test_user

hello.txt
Hello ${name}
```

The `src/main/resources/hello.txt` created in target directory as a result of build process doesn't have the expected content.

```
Expected hello.txt
Hello test_user

Actual hello.txt
Hello ${name}
```

Can somebody please explain what am I doing wrong ?

PS: I added ant task to print project property ${name} to check functioning of properties-maven-plugin and it seems to be working fine.

**Answer**: If anyone else is facing the same problem, then try this out-

Turn off **Build Automatically** on your IDE(Eclipse in my case) and then build your project. What maybe going wrong is your IDE keeps on building the project(replacing properties in resources) earlier than the runtime project properties are set by properties-maven-plugin. It worked for me.

Comment: Please make a full working example on github so I can take a look ...

Answer (score 0):

To filter resources the convention is to keep the files to be filtered in `src/main/resources` and do the filter via:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

If you like to include/exclude files you can use the includes/excludes parts like this:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
          <include>**/*.rtf</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

There is no need to use properties-maven-plugin to read the properties and explicitly to add the maven-resources-plugin to the life cycle cause it is there by default.

Comment: I removed maven-resources-plugin declaration as you suggested. Now the resources to be replaced are specified in build element. It still doesn't work. Also, my use case involves properties-maven-plugin. Can you suggest any other alternative ?